# Advanced Custom Field - Displaying a youtube video on a Woocommerce template

Tags: php, wordpress, youtube, advanced-custom-fields

I have set up a custom field which you add the end of a youtube link in through a text widget in wordpress from there a function adds this to an iframe in the url.

Below is the function adding this to the page:

```
                <?php if (($videoUrl = get_field('video_name', $post->ID)) != '') {
            //Extract the url arguments (everything after the '?'
            if (($query = parse_url($videoUrl, PHP_URL_QUERY)) != '') {
                //Convert the arguments into an array for each access
                parse_str($query, $arguments);
                if (array_key_exists('v', $arguments)) {
                    //Create the embed code using the id from the 'v' argument
                    $videoId = $arguments['v'];
                    ?>
            <div class="videoContainer">
                <iframe width="390" height="219" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $videoId ?>?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
            <?php 
        }
    }
} ?>
```

I have added this in with the content however nothing seems to be displaying still. Could someone please help me spot any bugs..

Comment: What does $videoId return

Comment: Check the `src` url of iframe and match, whether it is expected youtube url or not...

Answer (score 4):

Youtube video show in wordpress template using advanced custom field

1) create text field in acf.
example : text field name is video_url

2) Please enter a youtube video link in acf text field.

3) show anywhere in wordpress template page

```
<?php // use inside loop
echo $youtubevideo_code = wp_oembed_get( get_field('video_url') );
?>
```